# as3 close browser window with externalinterface.call

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i am trying to close browser window with button from flash using external call. this is what i have b ut it does not work and i cannot see why.

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

private function FnBackDown(event:MouseEvent):void {

ExternalInterface.call("window_close()");
    }
```

and in my html file that calls the flash:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function window_close(){
window.close();
}
</script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ExternalInterface.call` takes a String argument which is just the name of the function. You should call it like this:

```
ExternalInterface.call("window_close");
```

Comment: your suggestion gives an error when compiling "Access of undefined property window_close"

Comment: @Russ, forgot to put the quotes around window_close. See edited answer.

Comment: @Russ Try setting `window.opener=self` in the `window_close()` function before calling `window.close()`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately closing browser windows via flash->java in very hit and miss. You will find that it will work in some browsers but not others.

From what I understand, this is because of an attempt by Adobe to prevent certain behaviours being used maliciously.

Sorry I don't have a better answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works in all browsers I tried (Firefox,Chrome,Safari,IE8+)...

```
ExternalInterface.call('close');
```